# How to return the index value of an Enum?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, truffle, javascript

I am trying to build a simple double escrow contract. I have an enum for the state:

```
enum State { Created, Locked, Inactive }
State public state;
```

When I try to interact with the contract through the truffle console, I can get the enum type to return:

[image]

but I don't understand how to make comparisons with the returned value. Can someone tell me how to compare the returned value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a BigNumber: https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#a-note-on-big-numbers-in-web3js

Try this to get the idea:

```
> var stateReadable = state.toString(10);
> stateReadable
```

Hope it helps.

Update ... this will be a little rough because it's a picture and not code I can play with. You're returning a promise with this part. `return instance.state()`. Now, you have to do something with that promise.

`var state =` is a mistake, because you don't want it to be a promise.

I'm going to break it down a little bit for readability and illustration.

Try:

```
> var state;
> var contract;
> Escrow.deployed().then(function(instance) { contract = instance; });
> contract.state().then(function(value) { state = value) });
> state.toString(10);
```

As a scripted thing, I would probably chain these so things don't thunder ahead too fast. Wait for the instance, then query the function.

```
var state;
var escrow; // more conventional naming
Escrow.deployed()
.then(function(instance) { 
   escrow = instance; 
   return escrow.state(); // this way we know it won't get called until the instance returns
})
.then(function(response) { // now we do something with the promise we returned.
   state = response;
   console.log(state.toString(10);
});
```

See how the promises are starting to form a chain? You can keep returning promises, then close up the block and append `.then(...` to pass the results into the next step. In other words, if you need another interaction with the contract after my `console.log()`, you would `return` the function, and then carry on at `});` with another `.then()`.

Just going by sound here, so I hope I didn't flub the syntax.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but instead of returning an int, it is returning a promise.

Comment: I see what you mean. Updating.

Comment: Wow thank you so much! The explanation really helps as well.